# How to be 100% sure that goroutines are waited on condition?

Tags: go, conditional-statements

reading the book `Concurrency in Go` by Katherine Cox-Buday and there is example how to use Condition.Broadcast to wake up waiting goroutines. here is the example from the book

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type Button struct {
    Clicked *sync.Cond
}

func main() {
    button := &Button{Clicked: &sync.Cond{L: &sync.Mutex{}}}

    subscribe := func(c *sync.Cond, fn func()) {
        var goroutineRunning sync.WaitGroup
        goroutineRunning.Add(1)
        go func() {
            goroutineRunning.Done() //1
            c.L.Lock()
            // 2
            defer c.L.Unlock()
            c.Wait()
            fn()
        }()
        goroutineRunning.Wait()
    }

    var clickedRegistred sync.WaitGroup
    clickedRegistred.Add(2)

    subscribe(button.Clicked, func() {
        fmt.Println("Func #1")
        clickedRegistred.Done()
    })

    subscribe(button.Clicked, func() {
        fmt.Println("Func #2")
        clickedRegistred.Done()
    })

    button.Clicked.Broadcast()
    clickedRegistred.Wait()
}
```

is it code 100% concurrency safe?

is it possible situation when main goroutine continue the work and does broadcast before  func goroutines parked and waited the signal/broadcast from condition?

I mean the situation when func goroutines done their work at line //1 but did not acquire the condition lock yet and main goroutine do broadcast this time, is it possible?

my assumption the follow: should the line //1 be moved at place //2 to avoid this situation?

or there is no problem and the situation I discribed does not make sence?

Answer (score 1):

Your question has two parts, I think:

1. Does this code have a potential race bug?  Yes: see, e.g., [How do I know that all my goroutines are indeed waiting for a condition using golang's sync package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58368947/1256452)
2. Is moving the `Done` call a fix?  In this particular code, yes, but I would say, perhaps not a particularly *good* fix.  As [Andy Schweig notes in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58368947/how-do-i-know-that-all-my-goroutines-are-indeed-waiting-for-a-condition-using-go#comment103144880_58369619) on [his own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58369619/1256452), it's more typical for code that uses the condition's `Wait` method to loop:

   ```
   for some_boolean { c.Wait() }
   ```

   The code that calls `c.Signal` or `c.Broadcast` would set the boolean appropriately (here, to `false`) before calling `Signal` or `Broadcast`, to indicate that the waiter should now stop waiting.